# Regarding the Schwarz Reflection Principle, is getting the analyticity of f(z) on the real axis a consequence of the theorem itself,

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, reflection

or a consequence of Morera's Theorem?

Basically, I want to be able to cite it correctly, e.g., can I say we have not only continuity of f(z) along $R$ (by assumption) but also it turns out that $f(z)$ is also analytic along $R$ -- *because* of the Schwarz Reflection Principle.

Or do I say that we get the analyticity by Morera's Theorem?

Thanks,

Comment: Can't say yes or no to that. There are various versions with various hypotheses. Give us the _complete_ statement of the version you're wondering about, including all the hypotheses, and someone will say whether you can say that.

Comment: For example, the version of SRP stated on Wikipedia has analyticity as a conclusion (and uses Morera in the proof).

Comment: Hi Professor Ullrich, I basically have in mind what Ahlfors presents in his book, although I don't currently have it with me in person.  If I remember correctly, Ahlfors presents a version of the SRP, and then follows it up with a stronger version of it, and shows the analyticity of $f(z)$ along $R$.  I will try to revise and update this question post, when I revisit Ahlfors' book, but please feel free to comment further, if you know what I am already talking about, regarding his book.  Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Hi @GregMartin, thanks for your quick response -- please see my comment to Professor Ullrich.  I think what is presented in Wikipedia is the version that probably follows Ahlfors' presentation of the strong version of the SRP.  If this is the case, I'm just wondering whether I should cite the SRP or Morera's Thm for the analyticity of $f(z)$ along $R$.  (I need the analyticity along $R$, because I am trying to subsequently use Liouville's Theorem for entire functions.)  Thanks,

Comment: Cite the SRP. It uses Morera in its proof, but Morera alone doesn't say anything about this conclusion.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much, @zhw :-)